# Проверка хэш-значение SHA256 для всех файлов одновпеменно с сохраненным значением в «hashfile.txt»

Tags: java

```
private static boolean verifyHashToAll(String filePath, String hashStoragePath) {
        Map<String, String> storage = parseStorage(hashStoragePath);
         String apache_sha256="";
         File file = null;
       try {
           file = new File(filePath);
           FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            apache_sha256 = DigestUtils.sha256Hex(in);

        }
       catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       }
       catch (IOException ex) {
       }

       if(storage.containsKey(file.getPath())) {
           if(storage.get(file.getPath()).equals(apache_sha256)) {
               return true;
           }
       }
        return false;

    }

    private static Map<String, String> parseStorage(String storage){
        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

        String line = null;

        try {

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader( new FileReader(storage));

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] items = line.split(",");
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                data.put(items[0], items[1]);}
            }   

            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                storage + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + storage + "'");    
        }
        return data;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        final File root = new File("files");

        search(root);
        System.out.println("Does the file's checksum matches the expected one? " + verifyHash("files/firstFolder/names.txt", "hashfil.txt"));
        System.out.println("Does the file's checksum matches the expected one? " + verifyHash("files/secondFolder/phones.txt", "hashfil.txt"));
        System.out.println("Does the file's checksum matches the expected all files? " + verifyHashToAll("files", "hashfil.txt"));}
```

Comment: дополните вопрос, не понятна суть

Comment: у меня есть папка files а в ней две папки и у каждого свой текстовый документ(files/firstFolder/names.txt и files/secondFolder/phones.txt). Программа читает и записует хеш значение SHA256 в hashfile.txt. Потом мне надо проверить полученое значение этого текстого документа. Сначало одтельно(verifyHash("files/firstFolder/names.txt", "hashfil.txt")) - этот работает, а потом verifyHashToAll("files", "hashfil.txt") - в этом проблема

Comment: Что именно не получается, какая ошибка?

Comment: создание и проверка 3-го sout verifyHashToAll("files", "hashfil.txt").Первые два sout дают true. Последний false

Comment: может быть нужно посчитать хэш не для директории а для каждого файла по отдельности?